# Balancing BST in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm beginner in Racket, recently I'm working at trees in racket and i have no idea how to balancing BST ,,, I write a code to insert and build a BST but can't balancing the BST ( my code to insert and build a BST )

```
(define (insert element tree)
(cond ((null? tree)(list element '() '()))
    ((= element (car tree)) tre)
    ((< element (car tree))(list (car tree) (insert element (cadr tree)) (caddr tree)))
    (else (list (car tree) (cadr tree) (insert element (caddr tree))))))


(define (build-BST L)
   (build-BST-helper L '())) 
(define (build-BST-helper L tree)
 (cond ((null? L) tree)
 (else (build-BST-helper (cdr L) (insert (car L) tree)))))
```

Thx in advance :) ,,, Sorry for my English

Comment: Are you asking how to implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Insertion in Racket?  This question might still be too broad, you may need to take a stab at it and see if you hit a more specific issue that you can freely post here (there a lot of smart scheme/Racket programmers here, I am not one of them, but I have been helped by many over the years)

Comment: i have a BST (unbalance) ,, my question is how to balancing the tree ,,, by mean in every insertion make the tree balanced

Comment: I think what you are asking for is clear, it's just that besides asking for how to do it all you are demonstrating in your code is that you are ready to start adding whatever answer you may receive, and in this way the question is too broad.  Did you attempt to add a balancing function but get tripped up? Was there some aspect about balancing that you didn't understand? I'm just guessing what your specific issue was, but only you can narrow this question down.

Comment: There are several different algorithms for keeping a binary search tree balanced, each with its own trade-offs. Have you checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree? Which of the data structures do you want to implement in Racket?

Comment: simplest might be [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree). maintain tree height in each node; when you  insert into a left (right) branch and it becomes too deep (more than 1 higher than the other node), rotate right (left) i.e. in the opposite direction. that way the height difference at each node is always at most 1 and the tree is almost-balanced. too balanced,  in fact -- red-black trees need fewer rotations and are still O(log n) in depth, which is our goal here (though the code is more involved).

Comment: @WillNess yes that what I'm looking for ,,, but I'm not familiar with racket ,, so please if you can guide me to implement the idea of AVL tree in racket by a snipped code/function or any thing help me .. i will appreciate that 
Thank You :)

Comment: see http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Scheme for examples. there's also http://rosettacode.org/wiki/AVL_tree but it seems to have no Scheme or Racket entry at the moment. start with factorials, fibonaccis etc.